# Does Internet Explorer browser all versions supports XPath?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xpath

I am trying to get the element data using XPath technique in IE. but i saw there is no document.evaluate method in IE. So may i know **equivalant method** to work in **IE all versions.**

i tried "document.selectNodes(xpath);" but it does not works.

Comment: What kind of document do you want to use XPath with, is that an XML document loaded by XMLHttpRequest or an HTML document loaded in a browser window? And please explain which versions of IE you want to use XPath with, as "all" sounds a bit demanding in 2015 where I think the versions of IE supported by Microsoft are IE 9 and IE 11.

Comment: I want to use XPath with HTML document and the IE version that i need is IE 9+.

Comment: IE so far has no support for XPath over HTML documents, you would need to look into implementations done in Javascript, a search https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+xpath+implementation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 turns up several, I am not familiar with details about their use so you need to check that yourself.